# Can anyone identify these small orange growths? They're just over an inch long and just appeared in my North Florida backyard

Tags: identification, outdoor

These small orange growths are just over an inch long and just appeared in my North Florida backyard. The skin surface is smooth and they look *almost* like small bell peppers, but still different. I'm concerned they might be toxic - I have a dog and don't want her to get sick. I definitely didn't plant them. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: rake them up and move them along so you are not taking chances with your dog

Comment: It looks as they were dumped and not grown in that spot.  Several of the fruits appear to have scars where stems used to be.

Comment: They certainly didn't grow there.

Comment: Is there a palm tree nearby? This looks kind of like palm fruit to me.

Answer (score 3):

They appear to be the characteristic "red" seeds of the cardboard cycad (Zamia furfuracea).  It is not a true palm tree, but does have the appearance of a palm plant. The seeds (and plant) are known to be poisonous to dogs, so you might want to remove them - at least the seeds - for safety.  Here are some specific links that should answer all of your questions in more detail.  I hope this helps.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamia_furfuracea

https://dogappy.com/are-palm-tree-seeds-poisonous-to-dogs

https://www.arkive.org/cycad/zamia-furfuracea/image-G39976.html